# Правильно решена задача на C++(структуры)

Tags: c++

Всем, добрый день! Проверьте пожалуйста решение задачи!
Список содержит следующую информацию об учащихся : ФИО, дата рождения.
Вывести список в порядке возрастания дат рождения(без учета года)
//Список содержит следующую информацию об учащихся : ФИО, дата рождения.
//Вывести список в порядке возрастания дат рождения(без учета года)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct Studets {
    string  F; //Фамилия студента 
    string C; //имя студента
    int day; // день в который родился студент
    int motlth; //месяц в который родился студент

} temp;
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);                
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int const m = 3;
    Studets st[m]; //размерность  массива структур 
    string n1;
    string n2;
    string n3;
    int  d;
    int q;
    cout << "\t\tВводите данные студента" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cout << "\tВведите фамилию студента:" << "\t";
        cin >> n1; 
        cout << "\tВведите имя студента:" << "\t";
        cin >> n2;
        cout << "\tВведите день рождения студента" << "\t";
        cin >> d;
        cout << "\tВведите месяц рождения студента" << "\t";
        cin  >> q;
        if (d <= 31 || q <= 12) { //Проверка на правильность введеной даты
            st[i].F = n1;
            st[i].C = n2; //Заполнение полей структур
            st[i].day = d;
            st[i].motlth = q;
        }
        else { 
            cout << "Вы ввели несуществующую дату рождения" << endl;
            break;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    cout << "Даты рождения по возростанию" << endl;
    // сортировка массива структур
    for (int i = 0 ; i < m - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m - 1; j++) {

            if (st[i].day + st[i].motlth > st[i+1].day + st[i+1].motlth) {
                temp = st[i];
                st[i] = st[i + 1];
                st[i + 1] = temp;
            }
            }


        }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        cout << "Номер студента:\t " << i << endl;
        cout << "Фамилия:\t" << st[i].F << endl;
        cout << "Имя:\t" << st[i].C << endl;
        cout << "День рождения:\t" << st[i].day << endl;
        cout << "Месяц рождения:\t" << st[i].motlth << endl;
    } 


}
```

Comment: 29 февраля не является валидной датой

Comment: Проверка корректности дат неверна - если день меньше либо равен 31 месяц не проверяется, а если месяц меньше либо равен 12, можно ввести невалидный день. Также странный критерий сортировки - по нему первое февраля и второе января равны.